# How to make UILabel show the UISlider value?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uislider

I've tried to make a slider to show a percentage out of 100, but the label doesn't show that value correctly.

Comment: Set your `slider.minimumValue` to `0.0` and `slider.maximumValue` to `100.0` either in the Attributes Inspector or in code.

Comment: In `valueChanged:` you are just setting the value of the label to the value of the `UISlider` which will be between `0` and `1` as a floating point value. Instead you need to calculate a percentage (e.g. `sender.value * 100`) and use that to set the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `UISlider` has a default min and max of 0 and 1. So the slider is sending all kinds of fractional values as you move the slider such as 0.153343 and .53453545, etc. But you convert that number to an `Int`. That leaves you with only 0 and 1.

Either multiply the `sender.value * 100` or change the slider's max value to 100.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the maximumValue of the slider:

```
slider.maximumValue = 100
```

This will have the slider go between 0 and 100.

However, if you would not like to do this, try something like this:

```
@IBAction func valueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    let rounded = round(100 * sender.value) / 100
    let final = rounded * 100
    sliderLabel.text = "\(final)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Made for Objective C. If anybody need.

```
float founded = roundf(100*self.volumeViewSlider.value)/100;
float final = founded*100;
```